# Proper Bibliography Style

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am writing a paper with the `IEEEtran` conference document class, a skeleton of which is shown below.

```
\documentclass[conference, a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,library}
\end{document}
```

The reviewers insist on the following conditions in the reference list.

1. No italic fonts in the reference text, neither in the article title, nor in the journal name.
2. Month and year of references must appear before the page numbers (for conference proceedings and journal articles).

I have tried several bib styles including `IEEETran`, `amsplain`, `unsrt`, `apa` and some others, but none of them is meeting the criteria. The `acm` style nearly does the job, but it prints the authors' names in small caps which I don't think will be acceptable in a technical proceeding. Any suggestion on any new bib style or whether it's possible to tweak any existing style to meet the requirements?

Comment: It's certainly possible to tweak things, but I'm surprised that the reviewers are worrying about this. It's down to the editorial team to make decisions about this kind of style thing: what do they say? Also, is there somewhere with official guidelines on the style required?

Comment: @Joseph well, my paper has been accepted, but they are asking me to make those changes and then submit the camera ready version. They have an official guidelines and apart from the bibliographic issues, my template is compatible with their requirements. So do you think those aren't my responsibility?

Comment: Don't use conference mode of the `ieeetran` but use `ieeeconf` as recently most IEEE conferences are switching to. Besides, reviewers cannot dictate styles as Joseph commented. It's beyond their command. Just check the conference website for author toolkit and you are done. Especially bib style is fixed for a long time so that's an enthusiastic reviewer but also a wrong one.

Comment: Another common practice is to remove any month fields to save some space to fit the papers in 6 pages so nobody practically cares about the month. Recently the online and hardcopy versions of the papers started to have different publication dates so it is at the same time ambigous info.

Comment: @percusse are you suggesting replacing the first line of my file with \documentclass[ieeeconf, a4paper]{IEEEtran}   That's giving me a really bad results, putting all the authors' names and affiliations vertically on top of each other.

Comment: No `\documentclass{ieeeconf}`. Have a look at [this page](http://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/tex.php) for download and class file. Nevermind their dvi pdf comparison.

Comment: @percusse `\documentclass{IEEEconf}` is needed; case insensitive file system might load the correct file, but a warning would be issued because TeX is case sensitive in string comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The comments on your question should serve you well.  However, if you reach an impasse and need to make the two changes that you described, here is how you can do it.

1. Save a copy of `IEEEtran.bst` in the same directory as your main TeX file and make the following changes in it.  The latest version as of this post is version 1.14 (2015/08/26).
2. Find

```
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

...and replace it with `FUNCTION {emphasize}{}`.  This will prevent formatting any portion of your references list in italics.

3. It looks like `IEEEtran.bst` has two entry types that place the date after the pages:  `@article` and `@misc`.  It appears that `@inproceedings` already has the date before the pages.

In `FUNCTION {article}`, find these two lines:

```
  format.pages output
  format.date "year" output.warn
```

...and swap their order to put the date before the pages.

In `FUNCTION {misc}`, find these two lines:

```
  format.pages output
  format.date output
```

...and swap their order to put the date before the pages.

4. Re-compile/typeset your work, including running BibTeX again to capture these changes to the .bst file.